# iOS Search Bar is not detected in XCUI test framework for iOS 13 version

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios13, xcuitest

While using XCUI test framework, i am unable to record/identify the iPhone/iPad search bar for iOS 13 version devices/simulators.This is working fine in iOS 12 version devices.

This is the code i am trying "springBoard.searchFields.firstMatch" but it is not working in iOS 13 devices/simulators.

Anybody faced this issue?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This search field is a part of the Spotlight application. This code works fine on iOS 13 Simulator.

```swift
import XCTest
import XCTApps

class spotlight: XCTestCase {
    func testSpotlight13() {
        let springboard = XCTApps.springboard.app
        let spotlight = XCTApps.spotlight.app

        springboard.swipeDown()
        spotlight.textFields["SpotlightSearchField"].typeText("Hello, Mrudula")
        spotlight.buttons["Cancel"].tap()
    }
}
```

P.S. grab XCTApps here https://github.com/rzakhar/XCTApps